# programming for infopath form

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

I have a fully functional Infopath form published on a sharepoint list. Now I intend to include some functionality to the form by programming in vb.
But when I click on the Customize form I do not see the Developer tab in the infopath designer.
Is it because it is on a List. If yes how do I migrate it to a Library. 
I can recreate the form, But I do not know what exactly needs to be done to add code to infopath form. I am looking towards including simple functions like pre-populating the form field from the list values when user makes a selection on the form.